# The bound for the absolute norm of a bandlimited function using the L2 norm

Tags: functional-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, sampling-theory

For a finite vector space we know that $\|x\|_{\infty} \leq \|x\|_{2}.$

I am looking for something similar for the topological Paley-Wiener space (bandlimited and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ ). Specifically, I need something like
$$\|f\|_{\infty}\leq C \| f\|_{2},$$
for some constant $C$. I will formalise the problem as follows.

For simplicity we assume the bandwidth to be $\pi$. We know that a function $f$ in this space is written as $f(t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_k \frac{\mathrm{sin\pi(t-k)}}{\pi(t-k)}$. We also know that, because $\frac{\mathrm{sin\pi(t-k)}}{\pi(t-k)}$ is an orthonormal basis, we get $$\|c\|_{\ell^2}=\|f\|_{L^2}.$$

Moreover, we know that, because $\frac{\mathrm{sin\pi(t-k)}}{\pi(n-k)}=\delta_{nk}$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta, we get $f(k)=c_k$ and thus
$$\|f(k)\|_{\infty}=\|c\|_{\infty}\leq\|c\|_{\ell^2}=\|f\|_{L^2}.$$

The issue that arises here is that $f$ can be higher than its samples $\|f(k)\|_{\infty}$. Also, it feels that maybe this bound is getting a bit too loose. Does anyone know any way to get the bound I need? If you work in the field and give any insight, even without the solution, it would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$
\left|f\left(t\right)\right| \leq \lVert c\rVert_{\ell^{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{\sin\pi\left(t-k\right)}{\pi(t-k)}\right)^{2}} = \lVert f\rVert_{L^{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{\sin\pi\left(t-k\right)}{\pi(t-k)}\right)^{2}}.
$$

The sum in the square root you can use the bound $\lceil t\rceil - k \geq t-k \geq \lfloor t\rfloor - k$ and bound the terms where $k$ is closest to $t$ with

$$
\left|\frac{\sin\pi\left(t-k\right)}{\pi(t-k)}\right| \leq 1
$$

so you get something like

$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{\sin\pi\left(t-k\right)}{\pi(t-k)}\right)^{2}} \leq \sqrt{2\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\right)} = \sqrt{2\left(1+\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}\right)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Cauchy seems like the right approach. About the second part, it seems like the sum of squared cardinal sines converges to 1 (that's what a simulation shows). So it seems that one could get that the absolute norm of f is smaller than the L2 norm, which would be quite a clean result. However, that is not essential for me, as I can just denote the infinite sum by a constant independent of the input.